# The relationship between filter kernel size and code execution time

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, imagefilter

I want to find the relationship between filter window size and filter code execution time in python. As I increased the size of the kernel, the time increased in the same proportion, but from a certain point on, the time remained almost constant. What could be the reason?

```
kernel = np.ones((g,g), np.float32)/(g*g)
image_filtered = cv2.filter2D(image ,-1, kernel)
```

Filter Size & Time:

[image: Filter Size & Time]

Comment: Try a larger range of sizes, like 100, 200, etc. There might be a step for certain ranges of values. It's not always possible to determine complexity with a simple sampling on a few points.

Comment: Also what is the size of the image? Please provide a fully reproducible code.

Comment: I repeated 1000 times for each kernel size in the loop and showed the average times in the picture. I also tried for higher sizes and the time was almost constant.
Is it possible to do multi-threaded calculations for the size of the above kernels to reduce the time?
And can see inside the 2D filter function?

Comment: What is your image size ?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but: In frequency domain, filtering doesnt depend on the filter size, that's why, for some filter size from where on it is cheaper, DST ist used.

Comment: Have a look here: https://towardsdatascience.com/fourier-cnns-with-kernel-sizes-of-1024x1024-and-larger-29f513fd6120